# Task in tasks.json doesn't auto-start in a VSCode dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

This is my `tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Serve API",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "yarn nx run api:serve",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": true
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "default"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Serve Client",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "yarn nx run client:serve",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": true
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "default"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Serve API & Client",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Serve API",
                "Serve Client"
            ],
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The last task has no problem auto-starting normally, but doesn't auto-start when in a dev container. I have run the `Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder` command multiple times to no avail. Is there a setting I can set to permanently allow this option? Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123214) with VSCode that is now fixed.

Your configuration works for me (I copied it in .vscode/tasks.json, closed and reopened the container, and the tasks are executed).